# jquery - get text of html return

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

This is probably simple but i can't seem to find my answer...

i have an ajax call that returns html

```
 dataType: "html"
```

and it's returned 'msg' looks like:

```
<div id="x"><p>Hello</p></div>
```

and that gets dom-added to the top of a parent div:

```
ajax call...
request.done(function(msg) {
   $('#parent').prepend(msg);
}
```

The issue is, i DONT want to do this dom manipulation if it's text hasn't changed (as there are other effects that take place that i've truncated out.  (This is a notice display that checks for updates in an interval)

so, what i want to do is find "Hello" within msg and compare it against a current div x's p that may already be on page.  This second part is easy to address, but the first part, I need to do something like msg.text() to just get "Hello", but a few varities i tried failed.

pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `filter()` to find the text..

try this

```
$(msg).filter('div#x p').text(); //this  will give you hello
```

OR `find()`

```
 $(msg).find('div#x p').text();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work.   It gives me a null string (blank alert).

Comment: gives null... interesting.. have your tried with `find()`  since you have specified your response as HTML.. find() is another  way to get element from an object..`$(msg).find('div#x p').text()` ;

Comment: updated my answer.. anyways welcome.. glad it helped... :).. happy coding..:)

Answer (score 1):

So you can do the following :

Hold the text from the previus query in a variable

```
var previusData;
```

then after the first request add that data to the variable, you can do this by using filter or like this :

```
previusData = $("#x p").html();
```

then before adding it to the DOM do a check by adding a new varible

```
request.done(function(msg) {
   var currData = $("#x p").html();
   if(currData != previusData){
     $('#parent').prepend(msg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the "notice" isn't present on page load and it gets fetched after page load, you could use a global variable (or a namespace) to hold previous value of the response and every time a new response is received, match it against the already stored response; discard if not changed; or use if changed and update the global variable

```
var cached_response = '';
ajax call...
request.done(function(msg) {
   if(msg != cached_response){
      $('#parent').prepend(msg);
      cached_response = msg;
   }
}
```

Comment: it is loaded inline on page load.  This is to check for an update to the contents in semi real time.

Answer (score 1):

One way is, you can use regex form replacing all html tags like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = '<div id="x"><p>Hello</p></div>';
    console.log(text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""));
});
```

Just put this line in your script, and compare with the data.

Here is the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/cGnG5/1/

And another way is using [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function as told in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#parent').prepend($(msg).text());
```